# How to ignore single quotes which extracting file names in python

Tags: python

I have a file`(main.cpp)` containing list of other files. The format is as below:

```
FILE: 'addition.cpp'
FILE: 'matrix.cpp'
FILE: 'rate_of_interest.cpp'
```

My code is as below:

```
lines=mainfile.read().splitlines()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    line = line.strip()
    if "FILE:" in line:
        fileName = line.strip().split("FILE:")[1].strip()
    else 
       print "Invalid file"
```

This prints as below

```
'addition.cpp'
'matrix.cpp'
'rate_of_interest.cpp'
```

But I want as below,

```
addition.cpp
matrix.cpp
rate_of_interest.cpp
```

How can I remove single quotes? I am new to python, tried various way, but not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fileName = line.strip().split("FILE: ")[1].strip("'")`

Comment: @mile.k: it is only removing ending single quote

Comment: That's because of the whitespace after `FILE:`, try replacing `"FILE:"` with `"FILE: "`. I just edited that in.

Comment: Until there're few spaces after `FILE:`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to strip any character just do splitting on single quotes.

```
if "FILE:" in line:
    print(line.split("'")[1])
else 
   print "Invalid file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
fileName = line.strip().split("FILE:")[1].strip().replace("'", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use string [replace](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) method

```
str.replace("'","")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your list of filenames, do it like this.

```
#Parse Parse Parse until you get variable filenames (list)
filenames = #Some list of filenames
filenames = [name.replace("\"", "").replace("'", "") for name in filenames]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("in.cpp") as f:
    for line in  f:
        if line.startswith("FILE:"):
            print(line.split()[1].strip("'"))
```

Output:

```
addition.cpp
matrix.cpp
rate_of_interest.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

### A regex solution [`FILE:\s*'(.+)'`](https://regex101.com/r/gB7jQ5/1)

```
import re

data = """FILE: 'addition.cpp'
          FILE: 'matrix.cpp'
          FILE: 'rate_of_interest.cpp'
       """

for line in re.findall(r"FILE:\s*'(.+)'", data):
    print(line)
```

If you want to find filenames that are empty, change the `+` to `*` in the regex code above.